# Android - Animating Layers in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, zooming, rotation, layer

I'm trying to get to grips with using 'Canvas' in Android. I'm using SDK 1.5.

I've been able to rotate text, but the background gets rotated as well.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to put my background image on one layer and rotate text (or zoom text) on a second layer.

How would I go about creating different layers on the Canvas? And is there a limit to the number of layers that can be created?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use canvas. I used another method, but it's such a long time ago, I can't remember now. Sorry (it's me age!).